# A procedure imported by 'Esri.FileGDBAPI.DLL' could not be loaded

Tags: c#, esri-geodatabase

I'm having issues getting my `Esri.FileGDBAPI.DLL` to work. I have the other two files, `FileGDBAPI.dll, FileGDBAPID.dll` in my `bin` folder. I can only add the Esri dll to my references, the other two I get an error saying that they can't be added because they either aren't accessible, not COM components or valid assemblies.

This is the error I get when running it:

```
A procedure imported by 'Esri.FileGDBAPI.DLL' could not be loaded.
```

By the way, I also have the `FileGDB_DotNet.dll` file in my `Windows/system` directory and I'm using .Net4.0. Thanks!

Comment: What version of ArcGIS are you using?

Comment: Are the FileGDBAPI.dll and FileGDBAPID.dll in your path?  You may be able put them in the same folder as the Esri.FileGDBAPI.DLL.  I'm not sure though.

Comment: I added the directory where they are located to the path, but no go. I'm not sure what version at the moment.. it's an inherited project that doesn't work..